# Limit Twilio Results

Tags: twilio, limit, twilio-php

Please help me understand how to limit the results that the Twilio PHP helper library returns.

thus far, I have tried...

```
$sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client = new Client($sid, $token); 
foreach ($client->messages->read(array(),10) as $message) {
echo $message->body;
}
```

and

```
  $sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client = new Client($sid, $token); 
foreach ($client->messages->stream(array(),10) as $message) {
echo $message->body;
}
```

Comment: And...? Do you get an error? Do you get more records than expected?

Comment: I get zero results with the previous code. Removing the `array(),10` returns all possible results.

Comment: What is the version of your php library, you can find the number in /Twilio/VersionInfo.php ...? Are you using the latest patched Release 5.13.3 ..?

Comment: Was running 5.12.0. Updated to 5.13.3 and the function works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For others having this problem as @Teryakisan reported, he was using the 5.12.0 version of the library and he was not getting any results, when he removed `array(),10` from `read()` or `stream()`, all records were returned.

After updating the library to the latest version (at the time of this post) 'version 5.13.3' the code works as expected.

The version of the library can be found in the `/Twilio/VersionInfo.php` file.